# Как при помощи javascript отправить 3 post запроса?

Tags: ajax, javascript

Я делаю так:

```
 function Signup() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'Signup/SignupUser.php', true); // Открываем асинхронное соединение
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); // Отправляем кодировку
    xmlhttp.send("name=" + encodeURIComponent(name), "password=" + encodeURIComponent(password), "email=" + encodeURIComponent(email)); // Отправляем POST-запрос
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { // Ждём ответа от сервера
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { // Ответ пришёл
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) { // Сервер вернул код 200 (что хорошо)
          document.getElementById("sdf").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; // Выводим ответ сервера
        }
      }
    };
 }
```

Ошибка наверняка здесь

```
xmlhttp.send("name=" + encodeURIComponent(name), "password=" + encodeURIComponent(password), "email=" + encodeURIComponent(email));
```

Но что делать, не знаю :(

Comment: А что написано в консоли ошибок? Что именно не получается?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: vote is not defined

Comment: Ошибка падает из какой-то другой строки кода и означает, что переменная vote не определена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
xmlhttp.send("name=" + encodeURIComponent(name) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password) + "&email=" + encodeURIComponent(email));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Указан метод `POST` излишне выставлять заголовок `Content-Type`.
2. В `XMLHttpRequest.send` нужно подавать на вход или строку, или `null`, а не несколько параметров. Объедините все передаваемые параметры в одну строку через амперсанд `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Отправляйте их синхронно.